# Trouble Finding Big O Time for this loop

Tags: big-o

I'm trying to find the Big O running time for the following code snippet:

```
for( i = 0; i < n * n; i++ )
    for( j = 0; j < i; j++ )
        k++;
```

I'm not sure if it would be O(n^3) because of the multiplication of n, or just O(n^2). Some help would be appreciated :)

Comment: It might be helpful to check ["Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inner loop will execute exactly 0 + 1 + ... + n^2 - 2 + n^2 - 1 = (n^2)(n^2 - 1)/2 times (see [Arithmetic Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticSeries.html)), so it's actually O(n^4).

Answer (score 2):

for(i := 1 -> n ){
    for(j := 1 -> i ){
        something
   
 }
}

runs in O(n^2)[innermost loop runs 1,2,3....n times as the value of n increases, so in total it runs for a sum of 1+2+3...+n = O(n^2)]

in your sample code let i := 1 -> p where p = O(n^2)
then since the code runs in O(p^2) its running time will be O(n^4)

Using the Big-O notation can help you through some situations. Consider this : 
for(i =n/2; i < n; i++){
 for(j = 2; j < n; j=j*2){
  something
 }
}

the outer loop runs **O(n)** and the inner loop runs **O(log(n))**[ see it as constantly dividing n by 2 : definition of log]
so the total running time is : **O(n(logn))**

Comment: `for(i = n/2; i < n; i++)` iterates `O(n)` times, not `O(n^2)`. I also don't see what that example has to do with the question. As for your first code snippet being `O(n^2)`: that's true, but I think you'd need to explain *why* it's `O(n^2)` for the answer to be truly helpful.

Comment: @sepp2k : fixed errors. thnx for pointing out. I was just promoting the use of Big-O notation while calculating some complex nested loops...thought it would help

Answer (score 1):

A precise and formal way to find out the number of iterations of your algorithm:

[image]